# why do I get Segmentation fault (core dumped) even when I have access to the memory?

Tags: c, pointers

I understand that there are better implementations of this reverse string function, I even have made one better than this, but I just want to know why this isn't working.

I have `_strlen(char *)` function that returns the length of a string.

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void rev_string(char *s)
{    
        int length = _strlen(s);
        char *clone = s;
        char *tmp = malloc(length * sizeof(char));

        tmp += length;

        while (*clone)
        {
                *tmp = *clone;
                tmp--;
                clone++;
        }

        tmp += 1;

        //so if you print this and check it you can see the reversing was successful
        //but I couldnt assign it back to the main string;
        printf("TMP-->%s,s-->%s\n",tmp,s);
        
        //I have debugged the problem to be in the next while loop
        while (*tmp)
        {
                *s = *tmp;
                tmp ++;
                s++;
       }    
}

int main(void)
{
        char *str;
        str = "five";
        rev_string(str);
        printf("done");
        printf("%s\n",str);
        return (0);
}
```

I am trying to understand pointers in-depth and I don't really know much about them at this point so I really appreciate any answer.

Comment: In addition to the above comment, observe `tmp += length;` and then `*tmp = *clone;` i.e. out-of-bounds access (invalid write in this case) which is [Undefined Behavior](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/behavior). And, `tmp` has not been freed after allocation.

Comment: @user3121023, ok that is iteresteing but if that is the case why is `*tmp = *clone` working. isn't `tmp` a string and supposed to be read only in that logic

Comment: @Azeem Idont think that is the case becuse the code works fine to that point it even prints the reversed strnig befor shownig the segmentation faoult error message

Comment: @user3121023 that is very insightful thank you so much. A few more questions, why isn't `tmp` enough? and for how long is it going to be writable?(I mean can I keep rewriting to it after the first time)? Is there a way to solve this besides the one that has been recommended in the answers?

Comment: @EHM: Well, you can verify it with [valgrind](https://valgrind.org/). Anyway, here's the working code: https://godbolt.org/z/EnfTYT. You may observe the changes. You need an extra character for the null character and put it at the end of the copied string before printing it with `%s`. Otherwise, it would be an access-without-initialization and another UB because the memory allocated with `malloc()` is not initialized.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the documentation of [string literal](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/string_literal):

> String literals are not modifiable (and in fact may be placed in read-only memory such as .rodata). If a program attempts to modify the static array formed by a string literal, the behavior is undefined.

Example:

```
char* p = "Hello";
p[1] = 'M'; // Undefined behavior
char a[] = "Hello";
a[1] = 'M'; // OK: a is not a string literal
```

So, this

```
char *str = "five";
```

needs to be

```
char str[] = "five";
```

to be modifiable.

---

This statement

```
tmp += length;
```

makes `tmp` to point to the memory one element after the allocated array.

And, accessing it first time with

```
*tmp = *clone;
```

is out-of-bounds access which is [Undefined Behavior](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/behavior).

You can verify this with [valgrind](https://valgrind.org/).

---

You need to allocate one extra character to accommodate the null-character so the length would be:

```
const size_t length = strlen(s) + 1;
```

and, the allocation would be:

```
char* tmp = malloc(length * sizeof(*tmp));
//                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^
//                          sizeof to variable idiom
```

The allocated memory needs to be freed after use to avoid the memory leak.

---

Here's the working example ([live](https://godbolt.org/z/aa8rqG)):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void rev_string(char *s)
{
    const size_t length = strlen(s) + 1;
    char *clone = s;
    char *tmp = malloc(length * sizeof(*tmp));

    char *p = tmp + length - 1;
    *p = '\0';

    p--;

    while (*clone)
    {
        *p = *clone;
        p--;
        clone++;
    }

    ++p;

    printf("TMP: %s, s: %s\n", p, s);
    
    while (*p)
    {
        *s = *p;
        p++;
        s++;
    }

    free(tmp);
}

int main()
{
    char str[] = "five";
    rev_string(str);
    printf("%s\n",str);
    return (0);
}
```

Output:

```
TMP: evif, s: five
evif
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I will ream more about string literals, and how c allocates theses in memory

Comment: @EHM: You're welcome! Go through the list of [Undefined Behavior](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/behavior). And, always refer to the online [C reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c) for detailed documentation, examples, etc.

Answer (score 2):

Comment of @user3121023 completely correct.

but even if you do
s = tmp
that will not work because s it's just a copy.
Althoug your code can work if will pass **s

void rev_string(char **s)

int length = _strlen(*s);

Replace whole last loop with
*s = tmp

This will work as you expected.
But never do this in real programs, it's bad solution.

Comment: The problem is I can't take a pointer to a pointer as an input parameter. the challeng requres me to take a pointer. I undersatand there are other waays to do this but is there any othe way to fix this. And thnks for the answer, upvotes

Comment: so is it impossible to rewrite a memory that has been filled with strings, isn't there a way to empty them then reallocate them.

Comment: If you cannot change signature of method
If it shoud returns void and should take pointer on string and str should be created as literal, then it's impossible.
By the way if str would be malloc-ed your code would work.

Till it str = "five"
As @user3121023 mentioned it point to the readonly memory
"five" placed in .data section that could not be modified (not rewrite not cleaned up either)

So there is no "clean" way. There are some "dirty" ways. I don't think you look for them.